# UnCaught TypeError : adata.data.....indexof is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I am using jQuery datatable in my application and i am stuck with this issue now.
I load the table from SQL DB, using C# code in backend. It loads/Adds/Deletes fine so far.

After selecting a row when i click on Edit Button, it shows me this error -

"Uncaught TypeError: adata.data(...)[0][columnDefs[j].name].indexOf is not a function at altEditor..."

[image]

JavaScript -

```
@section ScriptsBlock { 
    <script src=".../datagrid/datatables/datatables.bundle.js?2"></script>
    <script src=".../datagrid/datatables/datatables.ajaxcalls.js"></script>
    <script src=".../datagrid/datatables/datatables.export.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var columnSet = [
                {
                    title: "ID",
                    id: "ID",
                    data: "id",
                    type: "text",
                    placeholderMsg: "Id from database",
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                    type: "readonly"
                },
                ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
            ]


            var myTable = $('#dt-basic-example').dataTable({
                dom: "<'row mb-3'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start'f><'col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end'B>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                    "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
                ajax: "/page?handler=pagehandler",
                columns: columnSet,
                select: 'single',
                altEditor: true,
                "pageLength": 50,
                responsive: true, 
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'selected',
                        text: '<i class="fal fa-times mr-1"></i> Delete',
                        name: 'delete',
                        className: 'btn-primary btn-sm mr-1'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'selected',
                        text: '<i class="fal fa-edit mr-1"></i> Edit',
                        name: 'edit',
                        className: 'btn-primary btn-sm mr-1 cust-edit'
                    },
                    {
                        text: '<i class="fal fa-plus mr-1"></i> Add',
                        name: 'add',
                        className: 'btn-success btn-sm mr-1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: '<i class="fal fa-sync mr-1"></i> Refresh',
                        name: 'refresh',
                        className: 'btn-primary btn-sm'
                    }
                ],
                onAddRow: function (dt, rowdata, success, error) {
                    var result = PostRow('page', 'Addhandler', rowdata, success, error);
                    success(JSON.stringify(rowdata));
                    error: error;
                },
                onEditRow: function (dt, rowdata, success, error) {
                    var result = PostRow('page', 'Edithandler', rowdata, success, error);
                    success(rowdata);
                    error: error;
                },
                onDeleteRow: function (dt, rowdata, success, error) {
                    var result = GetRow('page', 'DeleteHandler', { id: rowdata.id }, success, error);
                    success(rowdata);
                    error: error;
                },
            })
        });
    </script>
}
```

**PostRow function**

```
function PostRow(handler, method, rowdata, success, error) {
    var data;
    data = $.ajax({
        url: '/' + handler + '?handler=' + method + '',
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="tokenName"]').val());
        },
        data: rowdata,
        dataType: "text",
        success: success,
        error: error
    });
    return data;
}
```

After looking a few blogs , i tried changing the JQuery version , added JQuery-migrate-cdn but no luck.
I am not really sure where to look for this error and understand it. Any lead/ suggestion is welcome.